# jOOQ 3.9: "ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined" on joined tables with matching column names

Tags: java, sql, jooq

After the latest 3.9 update it seems that jOOQ is now using the new Oracle 12c row_limiting_clause for row limiting as opposed to the old 'rownum' syntax.  This causes a "ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined" in Oracle 12c on joined tables with matching column names.

```
select
    student.name,
    school.name
from student
join school on student.schoolId = school.id
offset 0 rows fetch next 25 rows only;
```

The new clause, however, according to Oracle's documentation [1],

> If the select list contains columns with identical names and you specify the row_limiting_clause, then an ORA-00918 error occurs. This error occurs whether the identically named columns are in the same table or in different tables.

This causes a problem when you try to select all the columns from two joined tables while using the row_limiting_clause.

If each of the columns is individually aliased, then the Record.into() will likely not work to automatically convert the returned Record into the two table records.

Is there any nice automagical way of mapping aliased columns into table records through jOOQ?

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue / regression in jOOQ 3.9 ([#5451](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5451)), which was fixed in jOOQ 3.9.1. As a workaround, you can use `SQLDialect.ORACLE11G` to revert to the "old" `ROWNUM` filtering emulation for `limit()` and `offset()`.

Answer (score 1):

Both columns have same identifier `name` which isn't allowed.

You can use aliases for name like this:

```
select
    student.name student_name,
    school.name school_name
from student
join school on student.schoolId = school.id
offset 0 rows fetch next 25 rows only;
```

Comment: You sir are correct.  However, I am looking for a way to map the returned Record--with aliased column names--into records of the type of tables the data is selected from.  ie. invoking the Record.into( ... ) rather than individually mapping the aliased columns into the correct type of record.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, here is the solution I went with for mapping the aliased columns into typed records:

```
// following the student, school scenario from the first post

// define the prefixes
final String st_prefix = "st_";
final String sc_prefix = "sc_";

// define the tables to map to at the end
// the table names themselves aren't getting aliased in this example, but the fields are
final Table<StudentsRecord> st = STUDENTS.as(STUDENTS.getName(), field -> st_prefix + field.getName());
final Table<SchoolsRecord> sc = SCHOOL.as(SCHOOLS.getName(), field -> sc_prefix + field.getName());

// define the aliased columns
final Field<?>[] stFields = Arrays.stream(STUDENTS.fields()).map(field -> field.as(st_prefix + field.getName())).toArray(Field[]::new);
final Field<?>[] scFields = Arrays.stream(SCHOOLS.field()).map(field -> field.as(sc_prefix + field.getName())).toArray(Field[]::new);

query = context.select(stFields, scFields)
   .from(STUDENTS)
   .join(SCHOOLS).on(STUDENTS.SCHOOL_ID.equal(SCHOOLS.SCHOOL_ID)
   .offset(0)
   .limit(25);

// map the aliased columns into the tables expecting aliased columns
return query.fetchInto(record -> new Tuple2<>(record.into(st), record.into(sc)));
```

This solution relies on a jOOQ 3.9 feature, 'functional aliases' 1.  This is used to create tables that aliased columns can map to using the Record.into() method.

This is the shortest solution--using the 12c features--that I can think of.

[1] https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4512